# Django: IntegrityError Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: django, django-models

Upon saving my user at registration I receive the error message below. Could someone explain why?

Thanks

**Error Message**

```
IntegrityError at /member/registration/
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /member/registration/
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

**view.py**

```
 if form.is_valid():
            # If form has passed all validation checks then continue to save member.
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                                            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                            email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                                            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
                                            )
            user.save()
            #member = User.get_profile()
            #member.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            #member.save()
            member = Member(
                            name=form.cleaned_data['name']
                            )
            member.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Member (models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: try `Member(user=user, name=form.cleaned_data['name'])`, the error says that `user` is not provided and `nullable`.

Comment: @okm i have tried user=user,name=form.cleaned_data['name'] but it does not save, no errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is when you're saving the member, not the user. When creating the member, you are not assigning the user.